# Is fast enumeration exception-safe in files compiled with -fobjc-arc-exceptions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I'm considering using exceptions for internal error handling inside a library I'm writing. If they are used, the library will be built with arc and `f-objc-arc-exceptions` enabled.

One issue with obj-c exceptions is that care must be taken not to throw through any code you don't know to be exception-safe. When a file is compiled with `-fobjc-arc-exceptions`, is the enumeration code added in by the compiler exception safe?

As far as I can tell, it should be, because I can't see any reason for it to do anything that requires cleanup. But I'd be much happier using it if this behaviour is documented somewhere.

**Edit:** I should clarify that when I say "using exceptions for internal error handling", I'm talking about nonfatal errors. So "exception-safe" here means that there should be no memory leaked, no unreleased locks, etc.

Comment: I dont think this is good  at all, we should avoid exceptions, BUT this is just a comment on what you are doing. *and yes, I know apple does it too unfortunately* - just my personal opinion. -- given that, Id assume that fast enumeration itself is 'exception safe'

Comment: @Daij-Djan I don't get why this attitude to exceptions exists amongst obj-c programmers (speaking as one myself). Aside from the issues I mention, the reasons seem to be historical as much as anything, dating to when memory had to be released manually and exceptions were a hack on top of longjmp. In the right circumstances, they can be extremely useful. Especially in iOS, where it is not permitted to fork a new process and abort() if it fails.

Comment: FWIW, iOS still uses setjmp/longjmp exceptions last I heard, for memory footprint reasons. I haven't checked in a while though, could be out of date info. Throwing an exception in the "zero cost" exception model can be very expensive.

Comment: The worst part of using any library that uses exceptions internally is running the app under the debugger with an exception breakpoint enabled. Your exception WILL trigger the breakpoint, even if you have a catch around it, and repeatedly hitting the Continue button until I arrive at an actual failure is not my idea of a good time.

Comment: @PeterHosey Please file a bug against that with a concrete example (and send me the #).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Do not use exceptions for *internal error handling*.**

At best, you'll end up with code that has a different design and feel than the system code.   The border between the two will always require maintenance and consideration in that it adds a "which side of the exception behavior fence am I on?"

In reality, it will be a maintenance nightmare.  Every time the code is refactored -- potentially to take advantage of new features in the system -- you'll constantly have to maintain the border between the two kinds of exception handling.

At worse, there will be a software update that changes an implementation detail and your app will start crashing.

The libraries were designed to not used exceptions for recoverable errors.   Your code should follow the same pattern if you want to minimize the cost of ownership of that code.

There are a couple of libraries on the system that have used exceptions internally for recoverable errors.  They are a constant source of bugs and maintenance headaches.

---

To answer your specific question, No, this is never safe:

```
@try {
    for ( id x in array ) { ... do something that might @throw ... }
} @finally {
    ...
}
```

When you `@throw` out of fast enumeration, your are throwing through a frame of Apple code and the behavior is documented as undefined.    In practice, such a simple pattern is likely going to work just fine, but "works by coincidence" has a significant maintenance cost.

Comment: Can this be extrapolated out to all of Apple-provided ObjC, then?

Comment: Even if you were to create your own root class then, technically, No, as long as you continue using the Apple supplied runtime, it wouldn't be "exception safe".  Technically and, in this case, binary compatibility is critical and, because there *are* places that rely on recoverable exceptions, it really can't be broken.   Realistically, though, Objective-C isn't particularly well suited to exception rich programming models (unlike, say, Java).

Comment: @bbum I agree with you totally of course but ... maybe you can answer me this though: WHY does apple do you use exceptions for recoverable, internal error handling. MAINLY CoreData BUT ALSO The URL Loading System do it.. they throw and catch it internally misusing exceptions for flow control

Comment: @Daij-Djan An implementation detail;  the team chose to go that route because they felt the benefit for their particular problem space outweighed the cost.

Comment: Thanks. The fast enumeration stuff I wasn't so sure about because it's added in by the compiler rather than being a call to the frameworks, so it's not clear whether I should consider it part of the language (which is exception-safe) or the frameworks (which are not). This definitely adds more "weird" to going the exceptions route.

Comment: @bbum Just so I understand, are you saying that the apple obj-c runtime isn't guaranteed to be exception safe, but that it happens to be in certain places?

Comment: @ChrisDevereux *Technically*, no, it isn't exception safe.  Realistically, it has to be for binary compatibility reasons alone.   The fast enumeration stuff is a combination of compiler syntax and calling through to the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol.

Comment: Objects like NSMutableArray detect if you modify an array while a fast enumeration is running. So it's unlikely that any modification of the array would work if the fast enumeration wasn't finished properly, for example because an exception was thrown. And if it works today, there is absolutely no reason to assume it will work in the next OS version.